# syntax error with dynamic ALTER sqlite3_bind_text statement in obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

This code throws a error `[logging] near "?": syntax error in "ALTER TABLE jobs ADD COLUMN ? text"`

```
    NSArray *uArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"string1", @"string2", @"etc", nil];

    const char *query = "ALTER TABLE jobs ADD COLUMN ? TEXT NOT NULL";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement = nil;

    sqlite3_exec((sqlite3 *)(db), "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);
    if(sqlite3_prepare((sqlite3 *)(db), query, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
      for (NSString *obj in uArray)
      {
          sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [obj UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
          if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE) NSLog(@"DB not updated. Error: %s",sqlite3_errmsg((sqlite3 *)(db)));
          if (sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_OK) NSLog(@"SQL Error: %s",sqlite3_errmsg((sqlite3 *)(db)));
      }
    }
```

I can't see it saying anywhere that ? can't be used with ALTER

Thoughts

Comment: You can't use parameters for table or column names

Answer (score 0):

You can't use parameters for table or column names